# For loop skipping over certain folders

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through sub folders in a directory, but my for loop is skipping over some folders for a reason that is not clear to me, despite having the same name structure and properties as the other folders in the directory. I should add that the directory is a mapped network drive, but I'm not sure why that would matter. I've tried both os.walk and listdir to pick up the names of the folders:

```
root = r"mydir"

for directory, subdirectory, files in os.walk(mydir):
    print(directory)


def get_immediate_subdirectories(a_dir):
    return [name for name in os.listdir(a_dir)
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(a_dir, name))]
```

Is there a way to force the code to pick up everything in my main directory other than what I'm doing here?

```
Expected Output:

['11111-Apples',
 '11112-Bananas',
 '11113-Grapes',
 '11114-Oranges',
 '11115-Pears']

Actual Output:

['11112-Bananas',
'11113-Grapes',
'11115-Pears']
```

Comment: are this directories hidden directories?

Comment: negative - i can see them as clearly as the other folders

Comment: is there any pattern that those hidden folders follow?

Comment: which directories are missing?

Comment: Could you show the structure of your folder, the `expected` output and the `actual` output of the code?

Comment: Are you compairing your function `get_immediate_subdirectories` and the for loop ?

Comment: no - i just used two different methods, the first was the loop and then second was the function.

Comment: What sort of filesystem? Possible permission issues?

Comment: maybe compare the output of `stat` (from the command line) on the entries that appear vs. ones that don't?